# script to extract information from a webpage in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, scripting

### Background

I have a network performance testing tool which after every test,displays all its results in a new results page. Below is my workflow to find the final value.(Details not relevant here but the html elements i am looking for might

1.Go to a section called "Data frame" ( which has a table with timestamp,transmit,recieve and percentage as columns) and get the time stamp when percentage first drops below 99.9
Here is a snippet of the "Data Frame" table
[Data frame snippet](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8434096)

2.Go to another section called "Data throughput" ( table with timestamp, throughput as columns) and get the maximum value of throughput before the previously found timestamp.

After every test, i have to do this manually, but there should be someway to automate this.

### Question

1.Is it possible to write a script ( maybe in javascript ) to automate my workflow for every new results page?

example algorithm

```
section = webpage.section_with_title("Data frames")
for each row in section
    find first my_timestamp with percent < 99.9
done

section2 = webpage.section_with_title("Data Throughput")
for each row in section2
    find max row.throughput if row.timestamp < my_timestamp
don
```

2.Once i write the script, how do i execute it in the web page?

3.Can i leverage the firefox/chrome developer console in some way ?

Note:I develop mostly in C,C++ and ruby with very basic experience in HTML and CSS. I have barely used javascript, but i have a vague idea that the browsers use it to handle the content of every page.

My thought process was to somehow execute the script through firefox console, and it will provide me with the results... is that difficult?

edit: since i am not familiar with the web development terms, ill put an a different choice of words...
1.i open up the results page
2.i open the console window of firefox/chrome
3.run my script(dont know what language).
4.i should get the result in the console. i do not want to modify the results page. i just need the result displayed to me(in the console, or to a text file).

Comment: If you want this to run on the back-end (server side), then use Selenium web-driver, on Java or Python. If you want your script to run on the front-end (client side), then add a Javascript section in your webpage. Add the relevant part of your webpage to your question, and will be able to give you more specific technical details.

Comment: it is a local server which generates these web pages. how can i save it offline and add it here?

Comment: Comment above updated

Comment: but i do not have access to modify the tool which generates these pages. My thought process was to somehow execute the script through firefox console, and it will provide me with the results... is that difficult?

Comment: Still, I do not understand if you want this to run on the server side or on client side

Comment: i am sorry if i am not able to make this clear.. i am a beginner in this. i want to execute some script on my client browser which is viewing this page.

Comment: OK, so you need to add `<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>` in your webpage, and implement whatever you want to do inside this section (where the `...`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45263/discussion-between-mikhail-and-barak-manos)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to do what you think using Javascript. Please look up `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: I cannot modify the web page. I was mostly looking at a script i can execute after the page is loaded through the browser. Maybe like selenium.

Comment: The idea is to make a http request, if it was me, I'd write this application, possibly in VB.net that will do this for me. You could also just write a javascript in a new page you can host on your local. Anything that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for you to start (in Java):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class YourClass
{
    private WebDriver webDriver = null;

    public void open() throws Exception
    {
        webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    public void close() throws Exception
    {
        webDriver.quit();
    }

    public void doStuff() throws Exception
    {
        WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.id(...));
        ...
        // Alternatively, it might be easier to parse the entire
        // page-source instead of searching elements in the DOM
        String pageSource = webDriver.getPageSource();
        ...
    }
}
```

You will need to download the following JAR files and add them in your project's class-path:

- selenium-java-2.xx.0.jar (currently xx=39)
- selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.0.jar (currently xx=39)